# Exiting using :? in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following at the top of my bash script:

```
 "${PROJECT_DIR:?"Need to set PROJECT_DIR by sourcing <project dir>/setup.sh"}"
 echo "D'oh!"
```

When I source this (using `.`) I get the following:

```
-bash: PROJECT_DIR: Need to set PROJECT_DIR by sourcing <project dir>/setup.sh
D'oh!
```

I was hoping to exit when the variable is not set.  Am I missing something?

Comment: `${name:?...}` only exits from a non-interactive shell. Did you source the script from an interactive shell?

Comment: Aha.  That's the problem.  This is interactive.  

The command works, though, it just doesn't exit the shell

Comment: Sourcing something in interactively, you'll want to use `return`, not `exit`, or else you'll cause the calling shell to quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `:?` isn't the right tool for the job. Consider instead:

```
[ -n "$PROJECT_DIR" ] || {
  echo "Need to set PROJECT_DIR by sourcing <project dir>/setup.sh" >&2
  return 1 || exit 1
}
```

`return` jumps out to the parent interpreter where it was before calling `source`. If it fails, presumably your script was executed rather than sourced, so we fall back to `exit` instead.